# Using JDBC Java string, to connect to mysql database in PHP

Tags: java, php, mysql, jdbc, mysqli

what i have is java application, that connects to the database. I have username, password and connection url string. Url string is like:

```
jdbc:mysql://example.ddns.net:3306/something?useSSL=false
```

Is there a way to use this in order to connect to this mysql database in php? Using something like mysqli?

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find you answer on:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

<?php
$servername = "example.ddns.net";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: This did not work for me, because there was probably no database selected. However, If I just add $dbname to the mysqli after $password, it works as it should!